# Unable to run requests or lxml modules although they are installed

Tags: python-3.x

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print ("buyers" , buyers)
print ("prices" , prices)
```

When i run the code, i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-   32\webscrape.py", line 1, in <module>
from lxml import html
```

ImportError: No module named 'lxml'

Although , when i try installing it through command prompt i get the following result.

```
Requirements already satisfied<-- to upgrade>c:\users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
```

I use windows 8. 
I have tried everything but I'm unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: Haven't you installed lxml for python2 unintentionally?

Comment: I have been using python 3 from the beginning

Comment: Could you show the commands you entered in order to install lxml? Also, the command you use to start your script? And run a python3 console showing the same error? And a python2 console showing the same error too? (Or do you mean python2 is completely absent from your computer?)